# Top 5 with dense_rank() in sql

Tags: sql, dense-rank

This is my sql query,

```
select  DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by  SUM(CASE WHEN X.Year = 2022 THEN X.[gp] END) desc)[rank] ,X.CardName[customer], X.CardCode, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN X.Year = 2022 THEN X.[sales] END) as [2022_sales],
            SUM(CASE WHEN X.Year = 2022 THEN X.[gp] END) as [2022_gp],
            MAX(CASE WHEN X.Year = 2022 THEN (X.[month]) END) as [2022_month],

            SUM(CASE WHEN X.Year = 2021 THEN X.[sales] END) as [2021_sales],
            SUM(CASE WHEN X.Year = 2021 THEN X.[gp] END) as [2021_gp] 
       
             from 
            (
            SELECT  year(T0.DocDate)[year], month(T0.DocDate)[month], T0.CardCode, T0.Cardname, T4.memo, T1.LineTotal as [sales], T1.GrssProfit-ISNULL(T1.U_Add_Cost_SGD,0) as [gp]
            FROM [dbo].[OINV]  T0 INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1]  T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[OITM]  T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
            INNER JOIN OITB T3 ON T2.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsGrpCod 
            INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode
            INNER JOIN OCRD T5 on T5.CardCode = T0.CardCode 
            WHERE T0.DocType <> 'S' AND T4.SlpName <> '-No Sales Employee-' and T0.[CANCELED] not in ('C','Y')
            Union all
            SELECT year(T0.DocDate)[year], month(T0.DocDate)[month], T0.CardCode, T0.Cardname, T4.memo, -T1.LineTotal as [Total Sales S$],(-T1.GrssProfit-ISNULL(-T1.U_Add_Cost_SGD,0)) as [Net GP S$]
            FROM ORIN T0  INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
            INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
            INNER JOIN OITB T3 ON T2.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsGrpCod 
            INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode
            INNER JOIN OCRD T5 on T5.CardCode = T0.CardCode
            WHERE T0.DocType <> 'S' AND T4.SlpName <> '-No Sales Employee-' and T1.BaseType != 203 and T0.[CANCELED] not in ('C','Y') 
            ) X where X.Memo ='Sales' 
          
            group by X.CardCode,X.CardName,X.month
```

Below is my result set based on the query

[image]

In this results i need to get Top 5 only irrespective of the repetitive column based on the customer name
my results should be like this

```
rank                 customer                                                                                             CardCode        2022_sales                              2022_gp                                 2022_month  2021_sales                              2021_gp
-------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1                    Schenker Singapore (Pte) Ltd                                                                         C-SGD-0957      289428.000000                           126525.820000                           7           3098.000000                             -335.750000
1                    Schenker Singapore (Pte) Ltd                                                                         C-SGD-0957      254743.000000                           103185.400000                           3           80358.400000                            28384.130000
2                    LF Logistics Services Pte Ltd                                                                        C-SGD-0486      194508.000000                           76663.540000                            2           2250.000000                             1024.320000
1                    Schenker Singapore (Pte) Ltd                                                                         C-SGD-0957      194067.000000                           70353.620000                            9           6348.000000                             2516.890000
1                    Schenker Singapore (Pte) Ltd                                                                         C-SGD-0957      140823.000000                           56298.490000                            6           2566.000000                             1467.400000
3                    Schneider Electric Asia Pte Ltd                                                                      C-SGD-0960      211109.100000                           50048.760000                            6           24341.300000                            5843.980000
4                    Robotpack Flexible Automation System (S) Pte Ltd                                                     C-SGD-1817      107100.000000                           49620.400000                            7           NULL                                    NULL
5                    Amazon Asia-Pacific Holdings Private Limited                                                         C-SGDSF-493229  142160.900000                           44902.040000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
T AS
(
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(
       ORDER BY SUM(CASE
                        WHEN X.Year = 2022
                        THEN X.[gp]
                    END) DESC) [rank], 
       X.CardName [customer], 
       X.CardCode, 
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN X.Year = 2022
               THEN X.[sales]
           END) AS [2022_sales], 
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN X.Year = 2022
               THEN X.[gp]
           END) AS [2022_gp], 
       MAX(CASE
               WHEN X.Year = 2022
               THEN(X.[month])
           END) AS [2022_month], 
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN X.Year = 2021
               THEN X.[sales]
           END) AS [2021_sales], 
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN X.Year = 2021
               THEN X.[gp]
           END) AS [2021_gp]
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(T0.DocDate) [year], 
           MONTH(T0.DocDate) [month], 
           T0.CardCode, 
           T0.Cardname, 
           T4.memo, 
           T1.LineTotal AS [sales], 
           T1.GrssProfit - ISNULL(T1.U_Add_Cost_SGD, 0) AS [gp]
    FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1] T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[OITM] T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
         INNER JOIN OITB T3 ON T2.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsGrpCod
         INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode
         INNER JOIN OCRD T5 ON T5.CardCode = T0.CardCode
    WHERE T0.DocType <> 'S'
          AND T4.SlpName <> '-No Sales Employee-'
          AND T0.[CANCELED] NOT IN('C', 'Y')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YEAR(T0.DocDate) [year], 
           MONTH(T0.DocDate) [month], 
           T0.CardCode, 
           T0.Cardname, 
           T4.memo, 
           -T1.LineTotal AS [Total Sales S$], 
           (-T1.GrssProfit - ISNULL(-T1.U_Add_Cost_SGD, 0)) AS [Net GP S$]
    FROM ORIN T0
         INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
         INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
         INNER JOIN OITB T3 ON T2.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsGrpCod
         INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode
         INNER JOIN OCRD T5 ON T5.CardCode = T0.CardCode
    WHERE T0.DocType <> 'S'
          AND T4.SlpName <> '-No Sales Employee-'
          AND T1.BaseType != 203
          AND T0.[CANCELED] NOT IN('C', 'Y')
) X
WHERE X.Memo = 'Sales'
GROUP BY X.CardCode, 
         X.CardName, 
         X.month
)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE "rank" <= 5;
```